# When expecting an exception we cannot verify called mocks

Tags: flutter, exception, flutter-mockito, dart-mockito

I have a unit test in flutter like this:

```
 test(
        'when an invalid access token is used the api service should throw an exception',
        () async {
          final authService = getAndRegisterAuthService(invalidToken: true);
          final service = APIServiceNetworkImpl();

          const request = APIRequest("/test");
          expect(
            () async => await service.get(request),
            throwsA(isA<DioException>()),
          );
          // CRITICAL LINE
          verify(authService.getAccessToken()).called(1);
        },
      );
```

Everything works as expected if I comment out the last line. But when I want to verify that a mocked method (in this case `getAccessToken`) is called, the test fails, but it does not show an error. How can I verify a mocked function call has happened in such a case?

Also, the verify works in a test case where the service does not throw an exception.

Comment: There is not enough information here for people to answer  What does `getAndRegisterAuthService` do?  Exactly what is mocked, how do you create the mock object, and where do you use it?

Comment: It's mocked with the mockito package and as you can see with the `verify` it has mocked the `getAccessToken` method. But that's not really the point here. The question is strictly about verifying mock calls after an exception is thrown, as in the regular case everything works as expected.

Comment: No, it is exactly the point.  You have not provided enough details for anyone to tell what you're doing wrong.  It's not clear from the code you've shown that the mocked object is used at all.  Please show the implementation of `getAndRegisterAuthService` or provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not getting the essence here.

Comment: Again, please post an example that can reproduce your problem.  If you properly set up a `Mock` and if the exception is thrown *after* the stubbed method is called on that `Mock`, there should be nothing that prevents you from verifying that the call to that stub.  If, however, the exception instead is thrown *before* the stub would be called, then obviously the `verify` check would fail.  You haven't shown any evidence that the stub should be called in the exceptional case.

Comment: The exception gets thrown after the mocked method is called, as I'm fully in control when it gets thrown. Your bare statement is the exact opposite of the question I have: It should be able to verify, but it does not, so why?

Comment: Once again: nobody can tell you why without seeing your code.  Your question seems to have the attitude that verifying calls never works if an exception is thrown later; that is simply not true, and it's trivial to create an example that shows it working.  *You* are doing something wrong.

Comment: Or let me be more precise: the `verify` failure indicates that the stub on your `Mock` was simply never called.  Nobody can tell you why your stub is not being called.  Maybe `getAndRegisterAuthService` is using a real object and not the `Mock` as you expect (you haven't even shown any code that creates a `Mock` object).  Maybe `getAndRegisterAuthService` has some other logic bug that prevents it from calling `getAccessToken` in this situation.  Without seeing code, who knows.